# Can I use a Kaggle Dataset with CC BY-NC-SA 4.0 license to create projects and publish it on GitHub?

Tags: github, license-notice, redistribution, open-data

I was searching for a relational dataset on Kaggle for my SQL Data Analysis project & found one such dataset - https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/olistbr/brazilian-ecommerce.

I have downloaded the data and imported it into PostgreSQL and started my analysis. Later I thought of publishing my work, i.e SQL queries and the modified data on GitHub, but found that there was CC BY-NC-SA 4.0 license mentioned for this dataset on Kaggle.

Can I publish my SQL Queries + modified dataset on GitHub with CC BY-NC-SA 4.0 as a license in the license.txt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fair disclosure: I'm not a lawyer.

With the CC BY-NC-SA 4.0 license, you can definitely redistribute both the original data and your derivative work (any modifications your performed or the SQL queries for the analysis) as long as you do so under the same license and provide attribution to the original work (usually a notice and a link back to the original data set).

Comment: Thank You for your answer